# How to keep an io.filesystemwatcher running indefinitely

Tags: powershell

I have two io.filesystem watchers set up to monitor a network and process data as needed, but it seems after a few days the script fails when the event should trigger due to a Error Code 80080005. Every time I have it call a com application I later have it close said com application, and then use:

```
Stop-Process -name POWERPNT -Force
```

What more can I do to avoid these failures? Should I just schedule it to restart once a day at a time when it won't be needed? Is there a way to monitor resource usage and determine when it is close to experiencing this error and have it restart then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheduler to create task that will do your command when errorcode occured, and restart you process/service